# I want to display a variable value where the variable name matches a concatenated string

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have eight integer variables declared and assigned as follows:

```
...
int priceOneRed, priceTwoRed, priceThreeRed, priceFourRed, priceOneBlue, priceTwoBlue, priceThreeBlue, priceFourBlue;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
...
priceOneRed=100;
priceTwoRed=200;
priceThreeRed=300;
priceFourRed=400;
priceOneBlue=1000;
priceTwoBlue=2000;
priceThreeBlue=3000;
priceFourBlue=4000;

}
```

I have two spinners. One has the following options: "One", "Two", "Three","Four".
The other has these options: "Red", "Blue".

After a user selects options from these two spinners, I concat the word "price" and the two options. E.g. price+One+Blue.

I want to be able to display the appropriate price(integer value) that corresponds the concatenated string. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple `Map` to do this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("priceOneRed", 100);
...    

Integer price = map.get(concatedString);
```

Comment: Imagine that OP wants to add one more color and one more number... then refactoring would be a nightmare every time if you don't separate the logic between the *count* and the *item color*... added to that, if you want to keep it as it is, then `switch` statement in that case would be simpler!

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is to create a simple `Map` with a key-value pairs as follows:

```
Map <String, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("Red", 100);
items.put("Blue",1000);
.......
// rest of the items
```

Then another `Map` for the count:

```
Map <String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
count.put("One", 1);
count.put("Two",2);
count.put("Three",3);
count.put("Four",4);
```

Then upon user's choice in the spinner, you do something like:

```
String countChoice = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(); // from first spinner
String itemChoice = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() // from second spinner
count.get(countChoice) + " " + itemChoice +  " " + items.get(itemChoice); // change to the appropriate textual format you want
```

Using a `Map` is better than a `switch` statement because it's expandable; i.e. if you want to re-factor your code and adding more options, you won't end up with a very long `switch` statement. In addition to the ease of copying/updating the data between the `ArrayAdapter` of the `Spinner` and the `Map`.